# Breaking the code inside a method assigns wrong online values

Tags: twincat

I have a function block, inside of which I have a method. When the method is called, it takes it's input REAL variable and sets the function block's internal variable, also type REAL. Now, for some reason, when i put a breakpoint inside the method, the value for that variable is completely wrong, and is always assigned the same value. Here is the code

```
METHOD PUBLIC LowerTheObject : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    nSpeedSetpoint      : INT;  // 0-32767 (0-21mm/min)
    fInsertionDistance  : REAL; // Milimeters
END_VAR

IF  bEnable AND eMotionStateInternal = E_FeedState.IDLE AND bInhibitMovementDown THEN
    LowerTheObject := TRUE;
    eMotionStateInternal := E_FeedState.AUTOMATIC_LOWERING;
    THIS^.fLoweringStartPosition := THIS^.fPosition;
    THIS^.nSpeedSetpoint := nSpeedSetpoint;
    THIS^.fInsertionDepth := TO_REAL(fInsertionDistance);
ELSE
    LowerTheObject := FALSE;
END_IF
```

When I call this method here is what happens:
[image: Online values when method is called]

Now comes the interesting part, which took me a while to even see it. The value of the variable is WRONG only, when I break the code inside the method. Breaking the code inside the function block, the variable gets assigned correct value:
[image]

To wrap it up, I am as confused as ever. Why does braking the code assign the wrong value? This is very wrong, the code can't be debugged properly. Is this a bug in this build of the TwinCAT?

I can guarantee that no other place in the code sets the value of the `fInsertionDepth`. I even added the TO_REAL(), in case the compiler did something weird I am not seeing. It seems like a memory allocation issue to me, I have tried restarting the PC, cleaning solution, re-activating the configuration, nothing helps.

Does anyone have a clue what might be happening, why is the variable fInsertionDepth get the 9.4 * 10^-38 when using a breakpoint, no matter what value is beeing assinged to it? I am running the solution on a local development machine, windows10, 64 bit as well as 64 bit CPU, never saw these issues before. Using TwinCAT 3, build 4024.25.

EDIT:
I have managed to make a project where this is very obviously replicated - I am not sure how/where to add attachments, so here is the code:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
END_VAR

ProgramExecution();


// Program that will containt FBs
PROGRAM ProgramExecution
VAR
    fbTest  : FB_Base;
END_VAR

fbTest();

// Base FB
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Base
VAR
    fbTest  : FB_Sub;
    fValue  : REAL := 10.0;
    bStart  : BOOL;
END_VAR

IF bStart THEN
    bStart := FALSE;
    fbTest.Method1(fValue := fValue);
END_IF
fbTest();

// Second FB, that is instantiated inside the base FB
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Sub
VAR
    fValue  : REAL;
    bCall   : BOOL;
END_VAR

// Method within the second FB
METHOD PUBLIC Method1 : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    fValue  : REAL;
END_VAR
IF TRUE THEN
    Method1 := TRUE;
    THIS^.fValue := fValue;
ELSE
    Method1 := FALSE;
END_IF
```

Here is the resulting error when breaking on the expression where the value is beeing assinged:
[image]

Comment: Could you extract crucial part of the code to a FB with one REAL variable and one method, so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow. One other thing i need to say, this only happens when you break on the expression. Then you need to step out of the method (F10), running to the expression with F5 will not result in this bug from my testing.

Comment: I have managed to replicate this! Is there a way I can add an attachment? Do I upload the project somewhere and give you a link? I am not that experienced with stack overflow and sharing data on here.

Comment: Editing the question is fine, I'll take a look once I have a free moment

Comment: Well, hate to be the 'It works on my machine' guy, but it does work on my machine. Checked on 2 PLCs - CX5130 and CX7080 and everything is fine, online value displays what is should display. But I was using TC 3.1.4024.12 and TC 3.1.4025 Can you provide binary representation of this 9.4e-38? Maybe looking at particular bits will tell us something

Comment: I was running this on my laptop as I was testing the code - I will try to use a CX8110 tomorrow to see if the same happens there, maybe this problem is related to Windows OS, excluding Winows CE (not sure what your PLCs have as their OS)?

Comment: CX5130 is running Win10, CX7080 - TC/RTOS (OS dedicated for this particular PLC)

Comment: This could be a glitch in the debugging display because the names of the variables are the same inside the method and the fb. Can you retry by renaming the variable you use inside the method to something different?

Comment: I tried renaming, it is not a glitch in displays. I can cobfirm the variable gets assigned this value.

Comment: I am currently quite busy, I will try and test this further once I have more time. Thanks for trying out different solutions so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a glitch in displays, this value is assigned at some point, because you working in the stack memory (because the variable is declared in a method). In the PLC world you don't have any garbage collector, you just overwrite the address in every cycle. The number what you can see in when you break is some remaining data. Sometime the debug display not fast enough to collect everything when you break, especially if you change tab on the break. (This display issue is depend on your engineering PC not on the target PLC.)

Comment: Iguess I'll take it as the answer, but definetly a bug in TwinCAT and should be fixed imho.